# Solve $\int_0^y\frac x{\cos(x)^2}dx = \frac12$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, inverse-function, trigonometric-integrals

My son as an exercise had to solve for $y$ in

$$\int_0^y\frac x{\cos(x)^2}dx = \frac12$$

and he didn't manage to do it, and neither do I. You can find the primitive of the integrand, turning the equation into

$$y\tan y + \log\left(\cos y\right) = \frac12,$$

but that doesn't seem easy to solve either.

Is there some kind of a closed-form solution? Note that this is secondary school, so I expect it to be possible without complex integration, though if you find a solution using complex integration I would be interested in seeing that as well.

Comment: Perhaps the question is: show that the equation has a solution.

Comment: The question should be $\int_0^y\frac x{\cos^2(x)}dx = \frac12$ instead of $\int_0^y\frac x{\cos(x)^2}dx = \frac12 right?$

Comment: @VinanthSBharadwaj Both notations exist, but I prefer $f(x)^2$, because no confusion is possible: $f^2(x)$ is sometimes used to mean $f\circ f(x)$, even more so with $f^{-1}(x)$ for the application of the inverse function.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I think the intended question was not that, but it could very well be that the question as it stands was harder than intended.

Comment: @doetoe I don't know where you read (or who taught you) that $f^2 = f\circ f$ but that notation is incredibily uncomfortable and really bad. Composition of functions are written explicitely.

Comment: @EnricoM. You have certainly seen $f^{-1}$ for the inverse function, or $\phi^n$ for the composition of automorphisms. But of course, since that notation is ambiguous, I try to avoid both uses of it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a nice solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%5Ctan%5Cleft%28y%5Cright%29%2B%5Cln%5Cleft%28%5Ccos%5Cleft%28y%5Cright%29%5Cright%29%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D

Comment: Her teacher must be saddist. It is an unsolvable question!

Answer (score 5):

Making the problem more general, we want to find the zero of function
$$f(y)=y \tan (y)+\log (\cos (y)) -k$$ This is a transcendental equation which requires numerical methods or *approximations*.

We can start using a series expansion
$$f(y)+k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ 4^{n-1} (2 n-1) (E_{2 n-1}(0)-E_{2 n-1}(1))}{(2n)!}\,y^{2n}$$ where appear Euler polynomials. The first coefficients are
$$\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{17}{360},
   \frac{31}{1575},\frac{691}{85050},\frac{10922}{3274425}
   ,\frac{929569}{681080400},\frac{3202291}{5746615875},\cdots\right\}$$

If you plot the function and this truncated expansion, you will notice that they match pretty well up to $y=1.25$ (at this point, the difference is  $0.054$ (which is not much since the functio value is $2.608$).

Now, we can try series reversion to get, as an *estimate*,
$$y=t-\frac{t^3}{4}+\frac{31 t^5}{288}-\frac{317
   t^7}{5760}+\frac{890453 t^9}{29030400}-\frac{896029
   t^{11}}{49766400}+O\left(t^{13}\right)$$ where $t=\sqrt{2k}$.

Trying for $k=\frac 12$ (which nicely corresponds to $t=1$) gives $$y=\frac{284012273}{348364800}=0.815273\cdots$$ while the exact solution given by Newton method for example is $y=0.822034\cdots$.

If I had used all the terms corresponding to the above table, the result would have been
$$y=\frac{66180692011972831}{80343513169920000}=0.823722\cdots$$

**Edit**

Anothe possibility is to use [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) instead of Taylor series. A very simple one would lead to
$$k=-\frac{9 y^2 \left(y^2-10\right)}{2 \left(7 y^4-54
   y^2+90\right)}$$ and we just need to solve a quadratic equation in $y^2$.

Tis would give $$y=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3 \left(6-\sqrt{26}\right)}=0.822031\cdots$$

And we can do much better.

**Update**

In his answer, @Bob Dobbs proposed to solve the cubic in $y^2$; it would write
$$4 y^6+9 y^4+18 y^2-18=0$$ The solution is simple
$$y=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 \sqrt{15} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{15}\right)\right)-3}=0.830347$$

Comment: I was trying to do something like this but couldn't figure out how to revert the series. How did you do it?

Comment: @bob. Basically using   https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html

Comment: I see that's pretty helpful. Thanks Claude.

Answer (score 1):

Maclaurin series $\ln\cos y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!(2n)}y^{2n}$ and
$\tan y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!}y^{2n-1}$ give
$$y\tan y+\ln\cos y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)(2n-1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!(2n)}y^{2n}=\frac12y^2+\frac14y^4+\frac19y^6+\frac{17}{360}y^8+...$$
I can't revert series like Bob (see the comment of Bob in Claude's answer), so I solved approximately by solving $\frac12y^2+\frac14y^4=\frac12$ which gave $y\approx\sqrt{\sqrt3 -1}\approx 0.855$. To get a better approximation I must solve $\frac12y^2+\frac14y^4+\frac19y^6=\frac12.$ But, I think I need a lot of time to do it by hand.

Comment: Don't be lazy, my friend ! (joke. The solution is simple and beautiful. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, one way to look for solutions is by using graphs. The red curve is $f(x) = \int_0^x t\sec^2 t\, dt$ and the blue line is just $g(x) = \frac12$. It is worth noting that $f$ is an even function, and so the solutions occur in pairs, as the image below suggests.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(y)=y\tan y+\log(\cos y).$
Then $F$ is continuous on $[0,{\pi\over 2})$ and
$F(0)=0.$ On the other hand
$$F\left ({\pi\over 3}\right )={\pi \over \sqrt{3}}-\log 2> \sqrt{3}-1>{1\over 2}$$
Therefore, there exists a solution $y_0$ such that $0<y_0<{\pi\over 3}.$